# When I slice for web in Photoshop I am getting results JPEG even I choose .png option

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, png, crop

I am trying to slice all image at one time using slice for web option, I selected .png 24 and I am getting results JPEG files. Is there any option to change this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you are saving, select all the slices with **Slice Select Tool**, then change the **Preset** to PNG.